# C to MIPS conversion

Tags: c, mips, do-while

In class we were learning how to convert C code to MIPS instructions, but i ran into a small problem. Just wanted some clarification as far as to what exactly the last line of the MIPS instructions was actually saying.

c:

```
do{ 
    i=i-2;
}while(i>1);
```

mips:

```
DO: addi s1,s1,-2    // i=i-2
    addi t0,t0, 1    // 1
    slt t1,t0,s1     // 1<i
    bne t1,$zero,DO  // ???
```

Comment: ***B***ranch ***N***ot ***E***qual. It's your loop. It jumps (branches) back up to the DO label unless the loop is complete.

Comment: The assembly-code does not correspond to the C-code. In particular `$t0` is incremented rather than set to one in the loop.

Comment: @EOF i assume its suppose to be addi t0, $zero, 1

Comment: @G.Mata: Or just use `slti $t1, $s1, 2` and invert the branch to `beq`.

Comment: Step #1 in learning *any* assembly language should be to get a programmers manual for the architecture that includes a quick-reference of mnemonics. That said, `bne` is pretty much universally branch not equal like Dan said.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland i have a reference sheet, i'm just not entirely sure why in the last line i'm checking if        i>1 != 0

Answer (score 0):

```
do{ 
  i=i-2;
  }while(i>1);
```

The assembly code for `while` and `do while` loops test the opposite condition of the one given in high-level code. If that opposite condition is `TRUE`, the `while` loop exit.

```
    addi $s1,$0,0      # i = 0
    addi $t1,$0,1      # j = 1   
while:
    addi $s1,$s1,-2    #i = i -2
    beq  $s1,$t1,done  #Branch to done If i = 1 (the opposite)
    j    while         # jump to while for loop through again
done:
```